# Single background for child elements

Tags: html, css

How do I set the one background for all inner-blocks

```HTML
<div class="outer-block">
   <div class="inner-block"></div>
   <div class="inner-block"></div>
   <div class="inner-block"></div>
</div>
```

To make it look like in the photo

[image]

In the example with the photo, I used the property:
background-attachment: fixed;

```css
.outer-block {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-block {
  background-image: url('./dsa.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

But this implementation has a drawback. When scrolling the page, the image remains fixed relative to the page.
Task: make sure that when scrolling, the internal blocks and the image move synchronously (expected behavior)

Comment: will you have content inside your div or it's only about the image?

Comment: Temani Afif, Yes, I will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pseudo element positioned relatively to the container and clipped at child level

```css
.outer-block {
  position: relative; /* relative on the container */
  width: 300px;
}
.inner-block {
  height: 150px;
  clip-path: inset(0); /* clip-path on the child */
  margin: 10px;
}
/* your background */
.inner-block:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/600) center/cover;
}
/**/

body {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-block">
  <div class="inner-block"></div>
  <div class="inner-block"></div>
  <div class="inner-block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! Ty Temani Afif

Answer (score 1):

Also...

```css
body {
  background : #032b52;
  margin     : 20px;
  }
.img-block {
  background : url('https://picsum.photos/id/42/400/700');
  width      : 400px;
  height     : 700px;
  border     : solid white 10px;
  }
.img-block > div {
  border       : solid white 5px;
  border-right : none;
  border-left  : none;
  background   : transparent;
  height       : 225px;
  width        : 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="img-block">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mister Jojo, this is interesting one. But actually in my case (not that one from example) I got grid in my parent block, and there might be more than one child block on one row. In this case you need to do something with vertical borders between blocks. Moreover in my case the grid is generated dynamically in compound component (React pattern), and it would be difficult to develop an algorithm for borders